# Weighting time series coefficients using model's likelihood

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, outliers

I have a question regarding to time series forecasting. In particular I've been working with a Bayesian approach, but I think the question is independent from that.

I have several time series which are very stable in time, except on specific dates that they have sudden changes. The problem is that if I use a forecasting technique that looks at the past to predict the future, such as ARIMA, the days after the sudden changes have high impact on the forecast.

Thus, to give a simple example, suppose I'm predicting $x_{t+1} = \sum \beta_j x_j, j<t+1$, I would like to add another weight witch accounts for the probability of $x_j$, something like $x_{t+1} = \sum f(x_j)\beta_j x_j, j<t+1$ where $f(x_j)$ is proportional to $P(x_j)$.

Thus, a sudden change has low probability and should not contribute to the prediction.

Does anyone know how to deal with these kind of problems? I'm trying to implement this in a Bayesian model, but I'm now sure how I should do it.

Comment: are you using R?

Comment: Have you tried using a [Particle Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter)?

Comment: @elsonidoq The problem I see with your description is that your weights, which are intended to offset sudden changes, do not condition on previous observations. Would you not want a weight that is framed like $w(x_j, x_{j-1})$? (I'm using $w$ and not $f$ as is conventional).

Comment: No, I have not tried to use a Particle Filter. However, I'm not sure how I would use Particle Filter for this case. How would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using ARIMA, but you need to consider deterministic impacts like outliers, level shifts, changes in trend, changes in seasonality, changes in parameters and changes in variance.  Look to the work of Ruey Tsay, Nathan Balke, Gregory Chow, Fox, Box, I. Chang.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the original question of estimating weights in a such a model.

Comment: I was trying to point them to the use of weighted least squares using Tsay's variance change test where deviations from the normal variance will be weighted less.  See here for more.  http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf  Chow's test could also be useful here in order to determine a break in the model and remove the older data.

Comment: Hi Tom! Thanks a lot! It seems that the work of Tsay really goes along in the same direction as I do! I will definitelly take a look into that!